# Open Source Flex Unit Testing Frameworks

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I was trying to use FlexUnit4 along with new Standard FlashBuilder and its asking me to upgrade to FlashBuilder Premium ,I cannot afford to upgrade to premium at this point of time .Can somebody please sugges an opensource alternative for Flex4 .

Sudeep

Answer (score 0):

Flex4 is actually two things, the IDE and the SDK. The IDE is not free, but the SDK is free and open-source. FlexUnit is also free and open-source. You can use both the SDK and FlexUnit without having to use the IDE.

The SDK can be [downloaded from Adobe's opensource site](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK). See the ["Getting Started" guide on FlexUnit Wiki](http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=GettingStarted) on how to set up FlexUnit.

A fantastic, fast, free alternative IDE is [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page).

If that doesn't work for you, you can also use any other text editor in conjunction with the FlexSDK compiler from the command line or in an Ant build script.